# React Native setState issues using true false and null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to setState on something that may be true false or null. I am having issues and looking for a clean way to code

does not work

```
setFullCalendar(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@calendar') === 'true' || null ? true: false);
```

Works but I can not set if null

```
setFullCalendar(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@calendar') === 'true' ? true: false);
```

Works but not clean. (not clean because I have over 10 of these todo)

```
const checkStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@calendar')
if(checkStorage == 'true'){
    setFullCalendar(true)
} else if (checkStorage !== null){
    setFullCalendar(true)
} else{
    setFullCalendar(false)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's only `false` if the value is `null`, just compare against that:

```
const checkStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@calendar');
setFullCalendar(checkStorage !== null);
```

Comment: Thank you, of course this would work. I am tried, I guess I need to call it a night

Answer (score 1):

You could use double negation to eliminate falsey values like null, undefined, false, "", etc... and get the right boolean result, keep in mind that empty objects, and empty arrays are truthy, not falsey values.

```
setFullCalendar(!!(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@calendar')));
```

or use the Boolean object to get the boolean result of that async action

```
setFullCalendar(Boolean(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@calendar')))
```